Bitbucket Runner on Multiple Servers
When I set up and open the runner on 2 different servers, the online GUI of Bitbucket for the pipelines shows corrupt and malformed error information.
For single server, the pipeline with a few steps work like a charm.
I don't want parallel step, I would like to initiate concurrency.
I set up the runner to 2 different servers and the pipeline is malformed and broken.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
